# GrammyJS: context changes between conversations

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, grammy

I am building a menu-like form for the user to input some data using a couple of buttons and for each button there is a conversation. I need the bot to be able to persist the user-context between the conversations.

I have some problems when using `ctx.session` and conversation.session.

1. Changing any props from `conversation.session` will reflect the change for all users using this bot.
2. Changing any props from `ctx.session` wont be shown in the next conversation.

Any ideas on how this should be done?